# foreach array keeps overwritten (beginner)

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

The next peace of code,

```
foreach (var trksegg in trk.Segs)
        { 
        double lon = Convert.ToDouble(trksegg.Longitude);
        double lat = Convert.ToDouble(trksegg.Latitude);
        double[,] lonlat = { { lon, lat } };
```

Looks like to keeps overwriting my lonlat array, so the array never gets bigger the [0,0] lon value and [0,1] lat value.

This probably is a beginners question(i'm beginner and cannot figure it out), but how can i fill the array with multiple valua's.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just put the array declaration outside the loop

```
double[,] lonlat = new double[trk.Segs.Length, 2];
for (int i=0; i<trk.Segs.Length; i++) {
    lonlat[i,0] = Convert.ToDouble(trk.Segs[i].Longitude);
    lonlat[i,1] = Convert.ToDouble(trk.Segs[i].Latitude);
}
```

there is also one little mistake: an array doesn't have an Add method, it supports only indexed access, so if you write

```
arr = { { lon, lat } }
```

in a loop, it will always reassign new array to your var, so it also makes no sense. in my example lon and lat are added via indexes

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the array inside your foreach loop, so it will create a new one each iteration of the loop.  You should declare it outside the loop and use it inside, then you'll get what you want.

So:

```
double[,] lonlat;

foreach(var trsksegg in trk.Segs)
{
    lonlat = { { lon, lat } };
}
```

Comment: Yes that's my problem; thank you very much for the explanation, but i go for the solution of @Mikant

Answer (score 0):

The `lonlat` variable is local to your `foreach` loop: the array it contains gets recreated in each iteration.

Arrays in C# cannot be grown. You could preallocate the array, as @Mikant does, or you could accumulate the results in a `List<T>`, or you could use LINQ:

```
var lonlats = trk.Segs.Select(
    trksegg => new[] {
        Convert.ToDouble(trksegg.Longitude),
        Convert.ToDouble(trksegg.Latitude)
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, but i go for the solution of @Mikant